# mysql_select_db in joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Working with 2 databases and I would like to select database before joomla query similar to `mysql_select_db` in core php.

Currently I am using below line to trigger all queries,

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
```

And I don't want to query like this,

```
select * from databasename.tablename;
```

Because it affects in my mysql replication.

Has anybody come across a similar issue ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper function like this

```
function getCustomDBO(){   
    jimport('joomla.database.database');
    jimport( 'joomla.database.table' );

    $conf =& JFactory::getConfig();

    $host       = '192.168.1.1'; //replace your IP or hostname
    $user       = 'db_user'; //database user
    $password   = 'db_pass';//database password
    $database   = 'db_name'; //database name
    $prefix     = 'jos_'; //prefix if any else just give any random value
    $driver     = 'mysql'; //here u can also have ms sql database driver, postgres, etc
    $debug      = $conf->getValue('config.debug');

    $options    = array ( 'driver' => $driver, 'host' => $host, 'user' => $user, 'password' => $password, 'database' => $database, 'prefix' => $prefix );

    $db =& JDatabase::getInstance( $options );

    if ( JError::isError($db) ) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
        jexit('Database Error: ' . $db->toString() );
    }

    if ($db->getErrorNum() > 0) {
        JError::raiseError(500 , 'JDatabase::getInstance: Could not connect to database <br />' . 'joomla.library:'.$db->getErrorNum().' - '.$db->getErrorMsg() );
    }

    $db->debug( $debug );
   }
```

Then you can just call it like SomeHelper::getCustomDBO();

eNJOY!!